# Can't upload image in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to upload an image in Symfony but the path is `null` in the database. I have the rest of champ in entity not null and the value write in Form.
The path is null but the rest (name and updated_at) is not null and have value write in form.

This is my Media.php:

```
<?php

    namespace ventenligneBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\validator\Constraints as Assert;

    /**
     * Media
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ventenligneBundle\Entity\MediaRepository")
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
     */
    class Media
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

         /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\COlumn(name="updated_at",type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        private $updateAt;

        /**
         * @ORM\PostLoad()
         */
        public function postLoad()
        {
            $this->updateAt = new \DateTime();
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
         */
        public $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        public $path;

        public $file;

          public function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            return __dir__.'/../../../web/uploads/produit';
        }

        public function getAbsolutePath()
        {
            return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        public function getAssetPath()
        {
            return 'uploads/'.$this->path;
        }

        /*
         *@ORM\PrepPersist()
         * @ORM\PreUpdate()
         */
        public function preUpload()
        {
            $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
            $this->oldFile = $this->getPath();
            $this->updateAt = new \DateTime();

            if (null !== $this->file)
                $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(),true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PostPersist()
         * @ORM\PostUpdate()
         */
        public function upload()
        {
                    $this->oldFile = $this->getPath();

            if (null !== $this->file) {
                $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(),$this->path);
                //unset($this->file);
                    $this->path=$this->getAbsolutePath();


                if ($this->oldFile != null) unlink($this->tempFile);
            }
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PreRemove()
         */
        public function preRemoveUpload()
        {
            $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PostRemove()
         */
        public function removeUpload()
        {
            if (file_exists($this->tempFile)) unlink($this->tempFile);
        }


        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }



        public function setPath($path)
        {
            $this->path = $path;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get path
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPath()
        {
            return $this->path;
        }


        /**
         * Get name
         *
         * @return \string
         */

         public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }



        /**
         * Set updateAt
         *
         * @param \DateTime $updateAt
         * @return Media
         */
        public function setUpdateAt($updateAt)
        {
            $this->updateAt = $updateAt;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get updateAt
         *
         * @return \DateTime
         */
        public function getUpdateAt()
        {
            return $this->updateAt;
        }

        /**
         * Set name
         *
         * @param string $name
         * @return Media
         */
        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }


    }
```

Produit.php:

```
<?php

    namespace ventenligneBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

    /**
     * Produit
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ventenligneBundle\Entity\ProduitRepository")
     * @UniqueEntity("nom", message=" Une Produit existe déjà avec ce nom.")  */
    class Produit
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=125)
         */

        private $nom;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
         */
        private $description;

        /**
         * @var float
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="prix", type="float")
         */
        private $prix;

        /**
         * @var boolean
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="disponible", type="boolean")
         */
        private $disponible;


        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="quantite", type="integer")
         */
        private $quantite;

        /**
        * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ventenligneBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist"})
        */
          private $image;


        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorie",inversedBy="produit")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_categorie", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $categorie;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
        return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set nom
         *
         * @param string $nom
         * @return Produit
         */
        public function setNom($nom)
        {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get nom
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getNom()
        {
        return $this->nom;
        }

        /**
         * Set description
         *
         * @param string $description
         * @return Produit
         */
        public function setDescription($description)
        {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get description
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getDescription()
        {
        return $this->description;
        }

        /**
         * Set prix
         *
         * @param float $prix
         * @return Produit
         */
        public function setPrix($prix)
        {
        $this->prix = $prix;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get prix
         *
         * @return float 
         */
        public function getPrix()
        {
        return $this->prix;
        }

        /**
         * Set disponible
         *
         * @param boolean $disponible
         * @return Produit
         */
        public function setDisponible($disponible)
        {
        $this->disponible = $disponible;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get disponible
         *
         * @return boolean 
         */
        public function getDisponible()
        {
        return $this->disponible;
        }

        /**
         * Set image
         *
         * @param \ventenligneBundle\Entity\Media $image
         * @return Produit
         */
        public function setImage(\ventenligneBundle\Entity\Media $image = null)
        {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get image
         *
         * @return \ventenligneBundle\Entity\Media 
         */
        public function getImage()
        {
        return $this->image;
        }

        /**
         * Set tva
         *
         * @param \ventenligneBundle\Entity\Tva $tva
         * @return Produit
         */
        public function setTva(\ventenligneBundle\Entity\Tva $tva = null)
        {
        $this->tva = $tva;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get tva
         *
         * @return \ventenligneBundle\Entity\Tva 
         */
        public function getTva()
        {
        return $this->tva;
        }

        /**
         * Set categorie
         *
         * @param \ventenligneBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie
         * @return Produit
         */
        public function setCategorie(\ventenligneBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie = null)
        {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get categorie
         *
         * @return \ventenligneBundle\Entity\Categorie 
         */
        public function getCategorie()
        {
        return $this->categorie;
        }

        /**
         * Set quantite
         *
         * @param integer $quantite
         * @return Produit
         */
        public function setQuantite($quantite)
        {
        $this->quantite = $quantite;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get quantite
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getQuantite()
        {
        return $this->quantite;
        }
    }
```

ProduitType.php:

```
<?php

    namespace ventenligneBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
    use ventenligneBundle\Form\MediaType;

    class ProduitType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('nom')
                ->add('description')
                ->add('prix')
                ->add('disponible')
                ->add('quantite')
                ->add('image' new MediaType())
                ->add('categorie')

            ;
        }

        /**
         * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
         */
        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'ventenligneBundle\Entity\Produit'
            ));
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return 'ventenlignebundle_produit';
        }
    }
```

This is a screenshot of the database:

[image]

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve the problem, could you add the `MediaType` class to our question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing to actually set `$file` in `Media.php` as there's no setter at all:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class Media
{
    /**
      * @Assert\File(maxSize="20M", mimeTypes={
          "application/pdf",
          "application/x-pdf",
          "application/zip",
          "application/x-gzip"
        })
    */
    public $file;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }
}
```

What I've also recognized, is that the path in `getUploadRootDir()` is:

> uploads/produit

But in `getAssetPath()` it's only:

> uploads

You could also make this DRY by using a function like:

```
protected function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'uploads/produits';
}
```

And then reuse it like:

```
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getAssetPath()
{
    return $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->path;
}
```

You could take it even a step further and make the path configurable through the `parameters.yaml`.